# Share Power BI report server reports to external users

Tags: powerbi, row-level-security

We have several reports on Power BI report server. Now we want to give access to external users including investors to view cost reports. I have researched a lot about this issue but for assurance I ask here, too. Is there any way to share this report with external users with RLS defined?

Any help would be much appreciated.